# Change image on hover by ID

Tags: jquery, css

```
<section id="wheel_section">
<nav class="position">
    <a href="#" class="pos-1">LOC 1</a>
</nav>
<nav class="position">
    <a href="#" class="pos-2">LOC 2</a>
</nav>
<nav class="position">
    <a href="#" class="pos-3">LOC 3</a>
</nav>
<nav class="position">
    <a href="#" class="pos-4">LOC 4</a>
</nav>
<nav class="position">
    <a href="#" class="pos-5">LOC 5</a>
</nav>
</section>
<section id="wheel_wheel">
<p>
    <img id="the_wheel" src="position_1.gif" width="233" height="233" align="absmiddle" />
</p>
</section>
```

Trying to change the image on hover (pos-1, pos-2, and so on...) the image from "the_wheel" needs to change. Those are gif's and as the id get's higher the gif will rotate faster. If i move the mouse on the left, the id's get's lower and the gif's will rotate slower, that's how they are made.

Tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#wheel_section .position .pos-1").hover(function () {
    $('img#the_wheel').attr("src", "position_1.gif");
});

$("#wheel_section .position .pos-2").hover(function () {
    $('img#the_wheel').attr("src", "position_2.gif");
});

$("#wheel_section .position .pos-3").hover(function () {
    $('img#the_wheel').attr("src", "position_3.gif");
});

$("#wheel_section .position .pos-4").hover(function () {
    $('img#the_wheel').attr("src", "position_4.gif");
});

$("#wheel_section .position .pos-5").hover(function () {
    $('img#the_wheel').attr("src", "position_5.gif");
});
});
```

But i guess there is a better aproach also.. Or am i wrong? :)

Comment: [Would something like this satisfy](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/RCyV6/)?

Comment: thanks. i copied the same code on my localhost, on hover will get position_undefined.gif

Comment: You have to change the markup also, that's why. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things:

- Preload your images
- DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)
- Use the power of jQuery collections

---

```
var wheels = [],
    wheelcount = 5;

// Preload the images
for(var i = 1; i <= wheelcount; i++)
    wheels.push($('<img/>').attr('src', 'position_' + i +'.gif'));

// Wire up the mouseenter event on each element
$("#wheel_section>nav>a").mouseenter(function() {
    var c = $(this).attr('class');
    var i = parseInt(c.substring(c.indexOf('-')+1)) - 1;
    $('img#the_wheel').attr('src', wheels[i].attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: thanks, almost good, only of i hover over the first link it gives me the second gif and for the last nothing :)

Comment: and also let's say if i hover the mouse over the 4th link, will load an image and if i move the mouse over another link the same loaded image will stay

Comment: awesome! for me is always hard to think like this :(, i code repeated :P thank you.

Comment: This will work only if your `a` elements will not contain any other class with a dash in them, such as `this-class-name`.

Comment: @Shef Agreed, this code is quite specific to the HTML provided. I do think that the html data attributes in your fiddle are a better option, but perhaps a bit outside of the OPs comprehension level.

Comment: maybe on the last line i can use ... replaceWith(wheels[i]); ?

Comment: no. sorry :) will re-appear the problem from my second comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably should cache the images first and then change them:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // preload and cache images
    var $pos1 = $('<img/>').attr('src', 'position_1.gif').attr('id', 'the_wheel');
    var $pos2 ...
    ...
    var $pos5 ...

    $("#wheel_section .position .pos-1").hover(function () {
        $('img#the_wheel').replaceWith($pos1);
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: hm, could you provide a test link or a jsfiddle - there might be something else going on.

Comment: To my surprise this solution seems to be [slightly faster](http://jsperf.com/dom-manipulation-vs-attribute-manipulation).

Comment: @joshperry The test says _"15% slower"_ for attribute manipulation on my side.

Comment: If you're worried about dead-raw speed, there are some [better options](http://jsperf.com/dom-manipulation-vs-attribute-manipulation/3).